# Use MATLAB to search for strings and return row numbers

Tags: matlab

I have a cell file that contains a single column of single letters like:

```
 G 
 G
 A 
 G
 U
```

and I want to be able to have my program search for a specific letter and then return the row number for each occurrence of that letter. I've been able to have my program find the certain letters by searching for strings, but I haven't been able to get it to return the row number yet.

Answer (score 2):

If the cell array is

```
 x = { 'G'
       'G'
       'A' 
       'G'
       'U'  };
```

and you want the rows for 'G', you can use

```
g_index = find( strcmp( x, 'G' ) )
```

which gives

```
g_index = [
     1   2   4 
]
```

if on the other hand, you just have a text variable (array of characters)

```
x = 
  G
  G
  A
  G
  U
```

then you should be able to do just

```
g_index = find(x=='G')
```